# Hiding the main div in children component Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Is there any way to hide the main div in a Vue app that is builded by Vue-CLI? I have tried appending display property but it didn't resolve the issue. I am trying to hide it inside the Channels component of mine. My main component looks like this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Channels/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Channels from './components/Channels'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Channels
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<template>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <template>
   <p>
   Am I wrapped around Div or Template?
 </p>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
</script>
```

You can inspect the parent of `p` tag in developer tools. It is `div` instead of `template`

Answer (score 1):

you mean `<div id="app">`?, you can delete it directly, but you should maintain that three is only one root in `<template>`

Comment: Yeah. I have done it by this statement : this.$parent.$el.style.display = "none";